# Javascript/React: Overflow X Visible, Overflow Y Auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is there a React/javascript based solution to fix the overflow-x-visible with overflow-y-auto issue?

I have a sticky sidebar in React that when clicked will reveal an options menu (see screenshots below). Researching, `overflow-x-visible` with `overflow-y-auto` is a ongoing issue. I've implemented a number of the proposed solutions including: `style="padding-bottom: 250px; margin-bottom: -250px;` and creating a wider div container [here](https://medium.com/@justicart/overflow-x-scroll-overflow-y-visible-c1a98238e002) and [here](https://www.gavsblog.com/blog/only-hide-css-overflow-on-a-single-x-or-y-axis-or-ignore-it). I've also been working through [this](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) tutorial. However, I can't get it to work for my use case.

Shortened code using Tailwind CSS:

```
<Sidebar className="h-96 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-visible">
    <SidebarItemNew className="relative">      
         <DropdownOptions className="absolute"/>
    </SidebarItemNew>     
</Sidebar>
```

[image: Overflow X visible. This is what I want to accomplish but with a y auto scrollbar]

[image: Overflow Y auto, X-Visible (code shown above)]

Any way to get this working for React? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could it be a problem with z-index ? If the container on the right is a different component it might be a problem with stacking [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (I'm speculating)

Comment: @RDU Your comment made me think and I'm going to explore portals in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html. From the docs: "A typical use case for portals is when a parent component has an overflow: hidden or z-index style, but you need the child to visually “break out” of its container. For example, dialogs, hovercards, and tooltips." Sounds promising!

Comment: We don't so "SOLVED" in the questions here. If you discovered your own answer, you can post and accept it. Otherwise you can delete your question

Comment: @j08691 Noted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I used React Portal to break the child element out of into its own DOM node. Then I used React Popper following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIUfTktVZRM) tutorial. It works great now!